# How to pass in type via method of variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, types

I want to deserialize an object at runtime and cannot figure out how to pass in the type without actually passing in model type.

E.g.

JsonConvert.DeserialzeObject(objectToDeserialize);

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Type runtimeType = Type.GetType("namespace_and_class_name");

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<runtimeType>(objectToDeserialize);
```

or something like:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type.GetType(stringOfType)>(objectToDeserialize);
```

Comment: Think about this, if what you wanted to do did actually work how would you write your next line of code that used `result` if `var` did not exist in the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [this other overload](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) instead:

```
object result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type);
```

Bear in mind that because the type is not known at compile time, the code cannot be generic anymore. You have to use `object` instead.

Comment: thank you very much. It worked a charm.